# How to call this method in c#?

Tags: c#, datagrid

How to call this method from another place?

```
private void AssortDatagrid_LoadRows(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (ValidTill.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataRowView rowContext = e.Row.DataContext as DataRowView;

        string item = rowContext.Row["Срок годности"].ToString();
        DateTime date;
        if ((DateTime.TryParseExact(item, "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                   DateTimeStyles.None,
                                   out date)) && (rowContext != null))
        {
            if (date.Date <= dt.Date)
            {
                try
                {

                    e.Row.Background = new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(rowColor) as SolidColorBrush;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else // когда не может парсировать дату
        {

        }

    }


}
```

I want to call it here:

```
private void workForce_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   AssortDatagrid_LoadRows(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
}
```

Is it possible to call it? 
Let me explain what I am doing. I want to call popup when rows are loading, inside popup I have circlular progress bar as gif animation. I am changing row background of those items whose valid date is soon.

Comment: Is the "another place" within the same class definition, or not?

Comment: What does the class structure look like where the caller/calling methods are located?

Comment: That method looks like an event handler - you will want to attach an event to be handled by the method.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't touch the UI controls in a worker thread. You'll have to invoke it in the UI thread.

Comment: i got this error The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @Servy It is in the same place

Comment: @David I am trying to show circular progress bar while Rows are loading

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov If you're updating the UI using results generated in a background worker you should use perform it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event so that it will automatically be run in the UI thread.  If it's done periodically to indicate progress, the `BackgroundWorker` has built in support for indicating progress; see the MSDN article for BGW more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no restrictions on event handlers that make them un-invokeable.  They have the same accessibility modifiers and Invocation rules as any other method group.  So you can Invoke the handler like any other method, optionally passing arguments with non-null values:

`AssortDatagrid_LoadRows(null, null);`

**UPDATE**
 
After receiving your comment:

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it."

This appears to be an Invocation problem...actually looks to be a WPF Invocation.

See [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

In this case something like...

`this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>AssortDatagrid_LoadRows(null, null))`

While this should resolve the Error...Servy makes an excellent point.  This type of work so be offloaded from the UI thread.  Push it off to a [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). I digress...we are going tangential to the original question.

Comment: It gave me this error The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov Which is an entirely different issue that is unrelated to the question as you are now calling `AssortDatagrid_LoadRows` from the `workForce_DoWork` method.

Comment: As to your edit, in context he should almost certainly just be doing the work in another one of the BGW's events, instead of the DoWork event, rather than using `Invoke`.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov I fixed his compiler error, but in any case, as I have said, it's not the proper avenue in this context anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can call event-handlers like any other method, but the better approach is to refactor the code and extract the contents of the event-handler as a normal method (with required parameters). Then call the method in both places (event-handler and the second place that you wanted to call the event handler).

Comment: `"You can call event-handlers like any other method"`  Well, they *are* methods.  As methods there no more special than any other; they simply happen to have a signature that matches some particular event.  The idea here is you're attaching a regular method to an event, not using an event handler like a method.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but usually you create event-hadnlers just to handle events, and you write some code in them, and then you realize that you need to also call the method from somewhere else. But you method's signature makes it inappropriate (or ugly) to call it manually.

Comment: Yes, and I attribute that to poor design of events in the MS framework personally; it's extraordinarily annoying that they use the signatures they do when they are virtually never appropriate.  In any case, the I find the arguments are very rarely actually used, so just passing in `null` values is usually acceptable, although I'm not opposed to re-factoring as you suggest.  Usually when I do I skip the named event handlers entirely and use a lambda as an event handler that calls out to the real method that has the arguments that are actually used.